# javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for SMTP error while running spring application using Intellij

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jetty

I have did several changes according to the other solutions but non of them were able to fix my issue. I get the following error while trying to run the application.

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for SMTP. Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for SMTP; message exceptions (1) are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for SMTP
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have changed the port number as 465 as well. But didn't worked. Many solutions have said to import javax.mail but I think I did it correctly.

These are the configurations

```
public class EmailConfiguration {

@Value("${mailSender.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${mailSender.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${mailSender.userName}")
private String userName;

@Value("${mailSender.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    mailSender.setUsername("adbuylk");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");
    return mailSender;
}
```

This is the service

```
public void sendEmail() {
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {

            Properties props = new Properties();

            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            message.setTo("sanduni@vclhq.com");
            message.setFrom("adbuylk@gmail.com");
            message.setText("This is a test mail");               

        }
    };
    mailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

This is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vcllabs.adsops</groupId>
    <artifactId>adsops-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.11.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

        <thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>1.3</thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>
        <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>1.4.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

        <hibernate-validator.version>5.3.4.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.12.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.41</mysql.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.6</commons-lang3.version>
        <jackson-annotations.version>2.8.0</jackson-annotations.version>
        <jackson-core.version>2.8.7</jackson-core.version>
        <jackson-databind.version>2.8.7</jackson-databind.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Thymeleaf dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>adsops</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.6.v20151106</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/adsops</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>redeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <hostname>${hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${port}</port>
                    <username>${username}</username>
                    <password>${password}</password>
                    <filename>${filename}</filename>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
-->


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: check over smtp mail provider or ask for you internet provider about smtp , my sample setting `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.xxx.net.np");`.

Comment: But sent an email without doing this. After that I did several changes to my code. After that this error occured

Comment: Did you enabled GMAIL for smtp? Otherwise you it won't let you interact. it's called "Allowing less secure apps to access your account" https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en if you login into your gmail and got to security settings, you'll need to enable that feature

Comment: @nuvio yes I have already did that. And I have sent an email using my account with another application as well

Comment: Have you tried with org.springframework.mail.MailSender instead? http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, and couldn't believe, when I decided to write `smtp` instead of `SMTP`. It solved it